# Pandas Dataframe of a sequence of grades

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a `pandas` `DataFrame` with two columns ("Nota de Título" and "Nota Total"). These two notes are stored in the following sequence:

```
"10 ;131,00 0; 131,00 130.00 10; 130.00 2 ;130.00 0 ;129.00 10 ;129.00 128,00 2; 128.00 10; 128,00 5; 127,00 127.00 127.00 5 ;127,00 0; 126,00 5 ;126,00 5 ;126,00 10; 126,00"
```

The first note should go in the first column, and the second note (which appears after the "`;`") should go in the second column. My code doesn't organize the data in this way. How can I fix it?
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd 

#Sequence of data 
sequence = "10 ;131,00 0; 131,00 130.00 10; 130.00 2 ;130.00  0 ;129.00  10 ;129.00  128,00 2; 128.00  10; 128,00 5; 127,00 127.00 127.00 5 ;127,00 0; 126,00 5 ;126,00 5 ;126,00 10; 126,00"
# Breaking the sequence in pair of grades
pares_notas = sequencia.split()
notas_titulo = [] #List of notas_titulo (First Colunm)
notas_total = []  #List of notas_total (Second Column)
for par in pares_notas:
   partes = par.split(';')
   nota_titulo = partes[0].strip()
   for nota in partes[1:]:
       notas_titulo.append(nota_titulo)
       notas_total.append(nota.strip())
df_notas = pd.DataFrame({'Nota de Título': notas_titulo, 'Nota Total': notas_total})
```

One exemple of the desired result for the dataframe, look the first pair of grades: `10; 131,00`
The result in the `DataFrame` should be like this:

An example of the desired result in the `DataFrame` is:

```
Nota de Título  Nota Total
10                131,00
0                  131,00
```

Each "Nota de Título" value is paired with the corresponding "Nota Total" value, creating a row in the dataframe.

Comment: and how this 3 values `; 131,00 130.00 10;` should be distributed between 2 columns?

Answer (score 0):

guess you can achieve what you want with:

```
import pandas as pd

sequence = "10 ;131,00 0; 131,00 130.00 10; 130.00 2 ;130.00  0 ;129.00  10 ;129.00  128,00 2; 128.00  10; 128,00 5; 127,00 127.00 127.00 5 ;127,00 0; 126,00 5 ;126,00 5 ;126,00 10; 126,00"
split_sequence = sequence.split()

notas_titulo = [x.replace(';', '').strip() for x in split_sequence if split_sequence.index(x) % 2 == 0]
notas_total = [x.replace(';', '').strip() for x in split_sequence if split_sequence.index(x) % 2 != 0]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['notas_titulo'] = notas_titulo
df['notas_total'] = notas_total
```